# How to prevent radioisotopes from entering the crust of a rocky planet

Tags: science-based, radioactivity

## Background

Earth has four main radioisotopes: <sup>40</sup>K, <sup>235</sup>U, <sup>238</sup>U, and <sup>232</sup>Th. These three elements (four primary isotopes) consist of most of the naturally occurring radioisotopes on earth. All of these elements are *lithophile* (rock-loving according to the Goldschmidt classification of elements) and don't sink down into the core of a rocky planet, instead staying in the crust and upper mantle (mostly). The reason for this is that these elements are super reactive and will want to go up to the crust where there are more reactive elements (oxygen mostly) and form compounds. From the comments, I have realized that potassium 40 is more concentrated in the core and so this question will focus on uranium and thorium.

## The Problem

Let's say that we have a rocky planet that is very rich in one or more of these radioisotopes (or something else, it really doesn't matter) and we're handwaving how the stuff got there in the first place. If life were ever to form (or colonize) this planet, they would have a problem with the radioactivity. *Now, I do get that if life were to form in this place, they would adapt and what not, but we are ignoring that for now.*

Is there any way to *naturally* prevent the radioisotopes from getting enriched in the crust (like make them stay in a deeper layer of the planet)?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question. For some set of reasons, you want a planet which is abnormally rich in uranium and thorium. For another set of reasons, you want a planet which is not richer in uranium and thorium than Earth. The two sets of reasons are contradictory, and you *have* to pick one them. (And anyway, there are [very good reasons](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/6557) to believe that Earth's core is much richer in potassium-40 than the crust is.)

Comment: I never said that I didn't want to have a planet with more and less uranium. I just am asking if there is a way to make a planet rich in radioisotopes but not clump them all in the crust and make deeper layers more rich in these elements. While <sup>40</sup>K is more rich in the core, then this question still applies to the another elements.

Comment: About Uranium not sinking, current scientific knowledge has it that it's all the Uranium below the crust that keeps the mantle and the outer core of the Earth in a liquid state. If Uranium didn't sink we would be standing on a geologically dead planet.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw That is true, but most of the uranium and thorium is sitting in the crust, not in the mantle or outer core.

Comment: I *still* don't get it. Whatever is in the deeper mantle and the core of the planet is of no importance whatsoever. No one can get at it, no one can extract it, no one can use it for anything. If it is not in the crust it might as well be in the Andromeda Nebula.

Comment: @AlexP Of course it has no use. I just want there to be a way for a majority of the radioisotopes to be stuck in the deeper layers of the world. How it's going to be used doesn't really matter.

Comment: @NeilIyer it sounds like you want an improbable planetary configuration which has no impact on the story and serves only to break suspension of disbelief. "Why" seems a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: It actually wan't meant to be part of my story; it was just a random idea that came into my head.

Comment: Could another way of saying things is that you want a solar system formed with sufficiently low metallicity  to avoid the vast majority of the actinides and above?

Comment: No not really, I just want there to be a way for a majority of the radioisotopes to be stuck in the deeper layers of the world (it doesn't matter how much radioisotopes is actually there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (...) naturally prevent the radioisotopes from getting enriched in the crust (...)?

## Sit and wait

But don't hold your breath. You may also need a planet around a red dwarf star for this, as the Sun won't live for long enough.

The half-life of $^{238}U$ is 4.5 billlion worlds (about as long as Valve will take to release Half-Life 3), whereas for $^{54}Fe$ it's in the order of $3.1 \times 10^{22}$ years.

What this means is if you wait, say, 18 billion years, the concentration of uranium goes down by a factor of 16, whereas iron stays practically the same.

Comment: Upvoted: as serious an answer as the question deserves,

Comment: Yes, that's where my mind goes as well when I read that word :)